# MySQL select data from one table where conditions are in other tables

Tags: mysql

My SQL is rusty and I have to solve one problem. I have data in three tables, as shown below. In both table1 and table2 columns username are unique!

I need to list addresses of all users (from table1) that have max(year)=2016 (in table 3) and also must be of type=0 (from table2).
Based on the data in the example, the result should be: **address3**

Any idea how should I do it with a single SQL command? I can (and I've done it) write a **php** script, but it should be one (complex) SQL command!

I tried join, inner join etc., but, as an occasional SQL user, my knowledge is limited, to say the least.

```
table1             table2         table3        
---------|--------  --------|----  --------|-----
username |address   username|type  username| year
---------|--------  --------|----  --------|-----
user1    |address1   user1  | 1    user1   | 2015
user2    |address2   user2  | 1    user1   | 2016
user3    |address3   user3  | 0    user1   | 2017
user4    |address4   user4  | 0    user2   | 2015
                                   user2   | 2016
                                   user3   | 2015
                                   user3   | 2016
                                   user4   | 2014
                                   user4   | 2015
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table1.address
from table1
     inner join table2 on table2.username = table1.username
     inner join 
                (select username, max(date) maxDate
                 from table3 
                 group by username) t3 on t3.username = table1.username
where table2.type = 0
      and t3.maxDate = 2016;
```

or

```
select table1.address
from table1
     inner join table2 on table2.username = table1.username
     inner join 
                (select username, max(date) maxDate
                 from table3 
                 group by username
                 having max(date) = 2016) t3 on t3.username = table1.username
where table2.type = 0;
```

Comment: What a wonderful world we are living in!
Just minutes after I posted the question two answers came.
@McNets answer (I used option 2) works great so I'm accepting that answer since it's a bit more clear (although I edited both options for the equality sign) and it seems that Avidos answer has a typo and I didn't check it, but I'm sure it will work!
In any case thanks to both McNets and Avidos.

Comment: It appears that I can not edit the accepted answer as I posted (or I don't know how?!). In order the answer to be consistent with the question asked, the sign before 2016 should be =. Of course, it obvious!
Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one, mate:

```
SELECT
-- I need to list addresses of all users (from table1)
    t1.username, t1.address
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.username = t1.username
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.username = t2.username
-- and also must be of type=0 (from table2)
WHERE t2.type = 0
-- that have max(year)=2016
HAVING MAX(t3.year) = 2016;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Avidos. It appears that you've edited your answer since I posted my comment to @McNets and accepted his answer!

Comment: @user3560520 yeah, edited a couple of times to provide the `simplest` answer I can provide while satisfying your question. cheers